# Resize LVM Group according physical partition

Tags: centos, partition, lvm

I have a new VPS with a 215 GB disk.

The disk has 2 partitions: first is /boot with 1 GB and the other partition has the remaining space:

```
lsblk -fm
NAME               FSTYPE      LABEL   UUID                                   MOUNTPOINT NAME                SIZE OWNER GROUP MODE
sda                                                                                      sda                 200G root  disk  brw-rw----
├─sda1             xfs                 fa254020-bb79-49c6-8745-d5f86dbfefb6   /boot      ├─sda1                1G root  disk  brw-rw----
└─sda2             LVM2_member         eawS39-uefJ-qqTo-M6Xa-QEcw-kbqf-4keDeq            └─sda2              199G root  disk  brw-rw----
  ├─vg_centos-root xfs         lv_root 8e5c474c-a30d-4541-bbfb-4ae541318971   /            ├─vg_centos-root   10G root  disk  brw-rw----
  ├─vg_centos-swap swap        lv_swap 42050010-7403-4678-b5d3-8534608e9c29   [SWAP]       ├─vg_centos-swap  3,9G root  disk  brw-rw----
  └─vg_centos-var  xfs         lv_var  7a2d4916-c422-4d8d-8b05-4dc9f4b1b734   /var         └─vg_centos-var  25,1G root  disk  brw-rw----
```

partiotion /dev/sda2 is a lvm partition witch now has 3 volumes (/, swap and /var) .

that partition had 40 GB of disk space, now it has 200 GB.
The thing is that the lvm group just recognize 40 GB of 200 GB in the partition, i need to extend the group to 200 GB

```
# vgdisplay 
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               vg_centos
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  5
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                3
  Open LV               3
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               <39,00 GiB
  PE Size               4,00 MiB
  Total PE              9983
  Alloc PE / Size       9983 / <39,00 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0   
  VG UUID               zqKkKI-g0ce-0Ii0-vL5C-FEsX-i69R-W9syXP
```

With pvdisplay:

```
# pvdisplay 
      --- Physical volume ---
      PV Name               /dev/sda2
      VG Name               vg_centos
      PV Size               <39,00 GiB / not usable 3,00 MiB
      Allocatable           yes (but full)
      PE Size               4,00 MiB
      Total PE              9983
      Free PE               0
      Allocated PE          9983
      PV UUID               eawS39-uefJ-qqTo-M6Xa-QEcw-kbqf-4keDeq
```

How can i resize the group vg_centos to use all the space of the partition?

Thanks.

Comment: If you found an answer, please post it *as an answer* (in the “Your Answer” box).

Answer (score -1):

I just found the answer with `pvresize /dev/sda2`